# "\" getting replaced with "\x5C" when writing to HBase database

Tags: json, regex, hbase

I have one Json string which I am writing to HBase as a column using Put Bytes.toBytes conversion.

The value of the Json is :  "^~\&"
But when I check the data in HBase database it is written like : "^~\x5C\x5C&"

How can I avoid such conversion in database?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Thanks and Regards,

Geeta

Answer (score 1):

It is not converted to that values, they are byte represantation of every char in your value. Hbase stores bytes, and shows byte[] in shell when you query. If you want to get real values, you should convert it to String again, after getting column value by Bytes.toString(columnVal) , like other data types as well.